# Is my approach for the RL circuit correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, thevenin

[image]

For the image above, i(0+) = i(0-) = 0A, and to get the IL(t) function, you solve for Rth, which is 50ohms. Afterwards, i'm confused with how to approach getting IL(t).

Comment: Generally, you use KCL or KVL to find the system of differential equations that describes this circuit and then solve them. Have you tried that?

Comment: I just realized that LOL. Do I assume Is(t) = 10u(t)?

Comment: Update: Figured it out. I forgot how to integrate LOL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is \$I_{L\left(t\right)}=10\:\text{A}\cdot\left(1-e^{\frac{R}{L}t}\right)\$.

It follows from:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_t}{R}+\frac{1}{L}\int V_t\:\text{d}t&=I_{s\left(t\right)}\\\\
\frac{1}{R}\frac{\text{d} V_t}{\text{d}t}+\frac{V_t}{L}&=\frac{\text{d}I_{s\left(t\right)}}{\text{d} t}=0
\end{align*}$$

During the period from \$t=0\$ to \$t=100\:\mu\text{s}\$, \$\frac{\text{d}I_{s\left(t\right)}}{\text{d} t}=0\$.

So, it follows for this period that:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d} V_t}{\text{d}t}&=-\frac{R}{L}V_t\\\\
\frac{\text{d} V_t}{V_t}&=-\frac{R}{L}\text{d}t\\\\
\int\frac{\text{d} V_t}{V_t}&=-\frac{R}{L}\int\text{d}t\\\\
\operatorname{ln}\left(V_t\right)&=-\frac{R}{L}t + C\\\\
V_t&=e^C\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}
\end{align*}$$

Given the initial conditions at \$t=0\$, then:

$$V_t=R\cdot 10\:\text{A}\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}$$

Now, it's easy. We know that;

$$\begin{align*}
I_{L\left(t\right)}&=\frac{1}{L}\int V_t\:\text{d} t\\\\
&=\frac{1}{L}\int R\cdot 10\:\text{A}\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\:\text{d} t\\\\
&=10\:\text{A}\cdot\frac{R}{L}\int e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\:\text{d} t\\\\\
&=10\:\text{A}\cdot\frac{R}{L}\frac{L}{R}\left(1- e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right)+C_0\\\\
&=10\:\text{A}\cdot\left(1- e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right)+C_0\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Here, \$C_0=0\$, so:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{L\left(t\right)}&=10\:\text{A}\cdot\left(1- e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right)\\\\
\end{align*}$$

So, at \$t=100\:\mu\text{S}\$, then \$I_{L\left(t=100\:\mu\text{s}\right)}= 6.3212\:\text{A}\$

Also,

$$V_{t=100\:\mu\text{s}}=R\cdot 10\:\text{A}\cdot e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}= 183.94\:\text{V}$$

You can work out the rest after \$t \gt 100\mu\text{s}\$.